# How to handle dynamic columns in Entity Framework Database First

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, architecture, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have 2 dbContext; one for code first approach (read & write to **database A**) and 2nd is for database first approach (read only from **database B**). My problem is number of columns in some tables of database B can vary.

---

So for client 1 Item table will contain

[image]

For client 2 Item table will contain
[image]

I can’t change structure of database B. I need suggestions how to generalize my data access layer and business layer for different clients especially for database first approach for database B. So that I can use data access layer & business layer as core for different client and add additional layer for client specific rules.

Answer (score -1):

The EF model cannot be dynamic so you would be ending up creating one EDMX for each database, that is unavoidable.

Once the DAL classes are created, you can use reflection to retrieve the type information and check for the table structure (as a property of the table class).

More information on reflection in .Net:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Reflection is a bad solution, adding to both complexity of code and performance.